# Which is the best approach to export 5 mil records of 50 columns. Datareader or BCP?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

The current program for data export doesn't expect the size, which uses the entity framework and converted the IQueryable to list for exporting. The Ram 16 GB is insufficient on operation.

I read that there are two options to avoid this like DataReader iterations and BCP. 
However I am unsure about 2 points.

1. Would BCP cause a memory issue in this case of 5 mil records.
2. Would Data reader be quite slow compared to BCP.

Could some one advise.

Comment: 1. No.  2. Depends.

Comment: It's quick to create a DataReader approach (which streams data back over the connection) so why not try it and see if it's fast enough? It's pretty fast in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

### Approach 1:

If You don't have any big BLOB data in results you want to export i would definitely go with DataReader (as @TrevorAsh points in comments). You can use it to copy data in batches, that will solve your memory issue.

So as soon as You start reading You can store results directly or in batches of size You choose. If its not fast enough You can divide results into multiple sets and read them in multiple threads, but that really depends on your scenario...

### Approach 2:

Alternative approach is to [partition](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1621/sql-server-partitioned-tables-with-multiple-filegroups-for-high-availability/) source data into multiple filegroups/files on SQL Server and then backup & copy only mdf file backup which contains your data

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I went ahead with data reader and it does very good. thanks.